# How to find limit of a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n e^x} {n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, sequence-of-function

How to find limit of a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n e^x} {n+1}$?  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n e^x}{n+1}$$

I have no idea how to evaluate this limit. I thought maybe I should rewrite $e^x$ using $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ but I am not sure whether I can do that or whether it would even help. If it is possible to evaluate the limit without L'Hospital's rule that would be the prefered way but I actually cannot see how L'Hospital would help with this problem.

Comment: Most things in that limit are constant (even $x$).  LHop works here.

Comment: Is it a typo in the question? $e^x$ does not depend on $n$, so that you can just pull it out of the limit.

Comment: No typo. I know I can pull it out but that's the task so I thought I was there for a reason so I kept it there.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: Well the the task is to find a limit of a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n e^x}{n+1}$

Comment: That's a different question than the one posed.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the same result if we compute

$$e^x\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

If $|x|\le 1$, it gives zero.

If $ x>1$, we write it as

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}e^{n(\ln(x)-\frac{\ln(n)}{n})}=+\infty$$

If $x<-1,$ the limite doesn't exist,
since for even indices, we find $+\infty$ ,and for odd ones, it gives $-\infty$.